# How to stretch resize Unity UI element on swipe in C#

Tags: unity-game-engine

[image: ...]

How stretch Unity UI with mouse or finger "swipe"?

I tried using [onDrag](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/846360/c-draggable-46-ui.html) to adjust the Left parameter of RectTransform:
[image: ...]
But it shows error that `transform.GetComponent<RectTransform>().rect;` is read-only and I cannot edit it.

Also I tried to

```
    Vector2 v2 = GetComponent<RectTransform>().sizeDelta;
    v2.x = Input.mousePosition.x;
    GetComponent<RectTransform>().sizeDelta = v2;
```

Which resized it **all** and I need just left edge to move, and right edge to remain in place:

[image]

What is good way to achieve it?
Thnx

Comment: can you increase the scale X?

Comment: well try to scale - it distorts 9-sliced image terribly. besides it moves both edges i need to move only  left one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to re-position the pivot.

Notice how your UI element is getting larger *from its center* (that is: both the left and right edges are moving as you add width).  This is because the pivot for the object is in the center (which it is, `(0.5, 0.5)`).  In order to make it scale outward only to the left you need to adjust the pivot to the right edge, `(1, 0.5)`

[image]